# How to pass a directory with test files to a xUnit test?

Tags: xunit

I have a xUnit test subproject which includes a directory where test data files are store.  Does xUnit provide any feature to access test data included with the source files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just get the current directory:

```cs
var workingDirectoryPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

This will give you working path like:

> C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PROJECT_NAME\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2

Then traverse upwards to the test project directory. From there you can proceed to the test data directory and perform any operations you like.